# Iframe, java applet, and z-index

Tags: java, html, iframe, applet, z-index

I have the following iframe that I added using javascript:

```
placeholder.append("<iframe id=\"oracleFormIframeToHide\" style=\"position:absolute;" +
        "top:25px;left:80px;overflow:auto;width:1100px;height:800px;\"frameborder=\"0\" src="+url+"></iframe>");
```

The 'src' points to a java applet. I am not able to show the java applet using the < object > tag because I don't have the .class file of the applet.
Anyway, my problem is that I would like to show a < div > on top of the < iframe >; z-index is not working for this purpose.
Any ideas?

Comment: did you set `z-index` for both your `div` and `iframe` ?

Comment: Applets are notorious for 'not playing nicely' with other elements in layers.  Just avoid even trying.  *Seriously.*

Comment: after hours of research, i'm afraid you might be right